# Extract all the words from a text file in bash

Tags: bash

I need to read all the words from a file to a variable. In addition to that I need to store each word only once. The selection will not be key sensitive so "**Hello**", "**hello**", "**hElLo**" and "**HELLO**" will count as the same word. If a word has an apostrophe, like the word "**it's**", it must ignore the "**'s**" and only count the "**it**" as a word.

To do that I used the following command:

```
#Stores the words of the file without duplicates
WORDS=`grep -o -E '\w+' $1 | sort -u -f`
```

The first two criteria are met but this method counts words like "**it's**" as two separate words "**it**" and "**s**".

Comment: Any other requirements? What about words like `they're` or `O'Malley` or `hello_world`?

Comment: In the case of `they're` it's going to ignore the `'re` and keep the `they`. We are not going to encounter words like `hello_world` so there is no reason work around them. I am not sure what the expected output for `O'Malley` is, but let's just ignore this for now

Comment: Is single quotes your only problem to solve for?  If it is so then 
maybe try a look behind regex like `(?<=\b)(?<!')\w+\b`
 https://regex101.com/r/XR54ed/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, something like that:

```sh
WORDS=$(grep -o -E "(\w|')+" words.txt | sed -e "s/'.*\$//" | sort -u -f)
```

**UPDATE**

Explanations:

- `var=$(...command...)` : Execute command (newer and better solution than `...command...`) and put standard output to `var` variable
- `grep -o -E "(\w|')+" words.txt` : Read file `words.txt` and apply `grep filter`

  - `grep` filter is : print only found tokens (`-o`) from extended (`-E`) rational expression `(\w|')+`. This expression is form extract characters of *words* (`\w` : synonym of `[_[:alnum:]]`, `alnum` is for alpha-numeric characters like `[0-9a-zA-Z]` for english/american but extended to many other characters for other languages) or (`|`) simple cote (`'`), one or more times (`+`) : see `man grep`
- The standard ouptut of `grep` is the standard input of next command `sed` with the pipe (`|`)
- `sed -e "s/'.*\$//"` : Execute (`-e`) expression `s/'.*\$//` :

  - `sed` expression is substitution (`s/`) of `'.*\$` (simple cote followed by zero or any characters to the end of line) by empty string (between the last two slashes (`//`)) : see `man sed`
- The standard ouptut of `sed` is the standard input of next command `sort` with the pipe (`|`)
- sort the result of `sed` and remove doubles (`-u` : uniq) and do not make a differences between upper and lower characters (case) : see `man sort`

Comment: Thank you so much it works. Do you have time to explain how exactly it works?

Comment: Explanations added